# How to get the most trends || interesting/most viewed videos from Youtube?

Tags: php, youtube

I was searching but couldn't find anywhere how to retrieve **random** video which is most viewed or trending this day or this week. How could I do that?

Comment: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No document hint a radom way. In fact, youtube use google search engine, as I know, there is no opinion set in all the google search api.

So if you want do a random show. You can catch all the standard result to database, then make them random show.

[most recent](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_recent)

[most viewed](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed)

[top rated](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated)

[most discussed](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_discussed)

[top favorites](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_favorites)

[recently featured](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/recently_featured)

[most responded](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_responded)

[most linked](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_linked)

Comment: These all are deprecated :(

Answer (score 8):

The YouTube Data API will allow you to do that.

You can find out more about it here:
http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Dude you just need to consult the [You Tube API](http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html)

For Example  you can use following urls to send requests to get
most recent

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_recent
```

most viewed

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed
```

Top rated

```
 http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated
```

etc. Consult the API, you will get the more information from there

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible, You can use YouTube authenticated Zend API

Read API methods from below link
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html

All the available methods are defined, so you be reading methods name you can guess what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

these are the methods in the youtube php api that gives you the opportunity to get a list of videos based on different criteria, then its easy to pick for example a random video from the top rated feeds.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos