# How to get the rss feed of most visited video of last 24 hours in youtube

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, rss

How to get RSS feed of the most visited video of last 24hours from youtube?
I wanna list the most visited video of last 24hour on the front page of my website using php

I already checked [this](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6224202?hl=en) but no rss feed generator found for this purpose.

[This](http://kworb.net/youtube/) website lists the most visited video of last 24 hours but I wonder what API or RSS feed it iuses!

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Try this [Youtube API 3 get latest videos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074112/youtube-api-3-get-latest-videos)
or use YT API [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search)

Answer (score 1):

This documentation, [Standard feeds for channels](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Channel_Standard_Feeds), also discusses on how to retrieve standard feeds that list the most viewed or most subscribed YouTube channels. To retrieve a standard channel feed, send a GET request to the URL associated with that feed.

You can also check the [`viewCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics.viewCount) property which gives the number of times the video has been viewed.

```
"statistics": {
    "viewCount": unsigned long,
    "likeCount": unsigned long,
    "dislikeCount": unsigned long,
    "favoriteCount": unsigned long,
    "commentCount": unsigned long
  },
```

You can check these related SO threads:

- [Youtube API to get most viewed video for a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648543/youtube-api-to-get-most-viewed-video-for-a-day)

> Yeah they don't have stats on a particular day but they do have a
>   running viewCount. So you can use the API info at
>
> ```
> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list
> ```
>
> to make something like
>
> ```
> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=viewCount&publishedAfter=2014-10-29T00%3A00%3A00Z&publishedBefore=2014-10-31T00%3A00%3A00Z&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
> ```

- [How to get the most trends || interesting/most viewed videos from Youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943406/how-to-get-the-most-trends-interesting-most-viewed-videos-from-youtube)
- [How can I get a list of the most viewed Youtube videos of the day by region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392757/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-most-viewed-youtube-videos-of-the-day-by-region)

Answer (score 0):

Like this I did it...
public void GetFeedList(int UserId, string channel)
{
var doc = XDocument.Load("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?" + channel);
XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
XNamespace media = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
XNamespace community = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/community";

```
        var query =

            from entry in doc.Root.Elements(xmlns + "entry")
            let grp = entry.Element(media + "group")
            let com = grp.Element(media + "community")

            select new YouTubeFeedItem
            {
                User_Id = UserId,

                User_Channel = channel,

                Title = (string)grp.Element(media + "title"),

                Description = (string)grp.Element(media + "description"),

                Video = (string)grp.Element(media + "content").Attribute("url"),

                Image = grp.Elements(media + "thumbnail")
                    .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("url"))
                    .First(),

                Views = com.Elements(media + "statistics")
                    //.Select(e => (string)com.Element("statistics"))
                    .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("views"))
                    .First(),

                Count = com.Elements(media + "starRating")
                    .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("count"))
                    .First(),

                Average = com.Elements(media + "starRating")
                    .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("average"))
                    .First(),

                Min = com.Elements(media + "starRating")
                    .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("min"))
                    .First(),

                Max = com.Elements(media + "starRating")
                    .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("max"))
                    .First(),

            };

        List<YouTubeFeedItem> youTubeFeed = query.ToList();
```

Cheers,
Jo